# Rails Check Box - Allowing User To Choose Days Off The Week

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have  a model name "Deal" and a string called "Days". I want to be able to allow my users to choose the number of days the Deal is available. It could be one day (Monday), or multiple days (Monday, Wednesday, Friday...) How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :monday %>
    <%= f.check_box :days, {}, "monday", "monday" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :tuesday %>    
   <%= f.check_box :days, {}, "tuesday", "tuesday" %>
</div>
```

But it overwrites the first option showing only "tuesday".

Do I have to add a string to the model for everyday of the week, or is there an easier option? Thanks.

**deals_controller:**

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @deals = Deal.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @deals }
  end
end

def show
  @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @deal }
  end
end

def create
  @deal = Deal.new(params[:deal])
  @deal.created_at = Time.now
  @deal.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @deal.save
      format.html { redirect_to @deal, notice: 'Deal was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @deal, status: :created, location: @deal }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @deal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
end
```

**deal.rb**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user    
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :days
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'll probably want to create a :day attribute (strings are probably easiest), and then use [Radio Buttons](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#radio-buttons) (rather than checkboxes) to allow users to only choose one of the options.

Your view would look something like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :day, "Choose the day:" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :day, "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday" %>
</div>
```

Alternately, you could use a [select tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags), like this:

```
<%= f.select_tag(:day, [['Monday', 'Monday'], ['Tuesday', 'Tuesday], ...]) %>
```

Am I answering the right question?

**EDIT** Hmm. Never tried that before. If you want the user to be able to select several days, it might be easiest to create a bunch of attr_accessor variables for each day, create a checkbox for each of those, and then have your controller or a before_validate action in the model update the :days attribute in your model (an array) to add all of the checked days to the array. The messy version of that model method would be something like this:

```
attr_accessible :days, ...
attr_accessor :monday, :tuesday, :wednesday...

before_validation :update_days

def update_days
  day_array = []

  day_array << "Monday" if self.monday == true
  day_array << "Tuesday" if self.tuesday == true
  ...

  self.update_attribute(:days, day_array)
end
```

and then, in your view, separate checkboxes for each temporary attribute:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :monday %>
    <%= f.check_box :monday %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tuesday %>
    <%= f.check_box :tuesday %>
</div>
```

You could even create a days helper in application_helper that is just an array of day symbols, so you could do something like:

```
<% days_of_the_week.each do |day| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label day %>
        <%= f.check_box day %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

to avoid repetition.

Again, not the cleanest way, but I think that would work, without your having to do anything other than change the days attribute to an array.

Comment: I actually want the User to check the number of Days they want the Deal to be available. (Could be a day or multiple days)

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking of doing, but I wanted to see if there was a better way. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Yeah. I'd expect there to be a better way, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is mostly correct. I suspect the error is in your controller. If you can post the controller's code, that might help us identify the problem, but I'll offer one possible solution.

With the code you have, Rails will parse the fields into a hash like `params[:deal][:days]`. That hash will hold an array of values representing the days. Before going too far, I think there is an error in your code. The prototype for the check_box function is

```
check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

You have provided the same value for `checked_value` and `unchecked_value`. Let's fix that and change it to

```
<%= f.check_box :days, {}, "tuesday", "" %>
```

Then, I believe the value your controller will receive would look something like

```
params[:deal][:days] == ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', '', '', 'Friday', '']
```

In the controller, you can loop through this array and assign them to your model.

```
deal.days.clear
params[:deal][:days].each do |day|
  deal.days << day if day.present?
end
```

I can't test this at the moment, so treat it as pseudocode that will hopefully get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I updated my question with the controller. Do I have to add something to it?